# Laravel page not found after creating .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, laravel-5

I'm using laravel for the first time i was used to work with lumen and i always used the .htaccess to redirect the root to the folder '/public' so i can call my routs directly from the root folder. but when i do the same on laravel it doesnt work telling me "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

Here is the .htaccess i used to add in lumen's root but doesn't work on laravel

`<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>`

what i'm i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try using this in your `.htaccess`. It works on mine. Cheers.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ ^$1 [N]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ server.php

</IfModule>
```